# Regex separate IP:Port from a log

Tags: regex, splunk

I have below simple regex expressions that works pretty well to split the given sample log. This would provides separate groups of object where I could access with $1 $2 $3 ... etc. I'm using this in Splunk.

Eg.

```
$1 = https
$2 = 2020-08-20T12:40:00.274478Z
$3 = app/my-aws-alb/e7538073dd1a6fd8
```

```html
(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+?)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)(.*?\s+)
```

```html
https 2020-08-20T12:40:00.274478Z app/my-aws-alb/e7538073dd1a6fd8 162.158.26.188:21098 172.0.51.37:80 0.000 0.004 0.000 405 405 974 424 "POST https://my-aws-alb-domain:443/api/ps/fpx/callback HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.2840.91 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-1:111111111111:targetgroup/my-aws-target-group/41dbd234b301e3d84 "Root=1-5f3e6f20-3fdasdsfffdsf" "api.mydomain.com" "arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-1:11111111111:certificate/be4344424-a40f-416e-8434c-88a8a3b072f5" 0 2020-08-20T12:40:00.270000Z "forward" "-" "-" "172.0.51.37:80" "405" "-" "-"
```

The problem here is, I want to separate IP:Port into separate group. There are multiple places which have the IP:Port. Those I need as a separate group like other object.

Eg.

```
$4 = 162.158.26.188
$5 = 21098 
$6 = 172.0.51.37
$7 = 80
```

Can anyone help on this? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps match all the ip number like formats with an optional port part `\b(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?::(\d+))?` https://regex101.com/r/Ul3VpF/1

Comment: Could you assist me to merge this to my above regex? I'm very new to regex operations.

Comment: I think all the fields are separated by a space right? So you start matching all the fields using `\S+ ` until you reach a value with an ip https://regex101.com/r/ZadSUI/1

Comment: Hmm.. I think I have a problem. The agent part of the log `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.2840.91 Safari/537.36"` seems to be having spaces. But I need to keep it in a single group. Any space within the quotes should be ignored. Will you be able to help on that as well?. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I see, you can match either any non whitespace chars except a doublequote, or match from an opening till closing double quote but the regex will be very long. https://regex101.com/r/n8X6vI/1 Perhaps there is a log parser available instead of using a regex. Or use findall and after that get the ip with the port from the list https://ideone.com/0oLOC9

Comment: Thanks for the support. you have given me a great tips. I'll work further to get this done. Meanwhile, If you found just share me complete regex to do this stuff. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Do you see any issue with something like this? https://regex101.com/r/ZadSUI/2

Comment: You can compose that pattern the way you want according to what you want to match. I can see that it matches multiple occurrences of `"` in a single group. Note that if the port is always present in the data, you don't have to make it optional `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?::(\d+))` But instead of using such a long pattern, I would consider first matching the separate parts into a list, and then after process it to get the desired values. https://ideone.com/0oLOC9

Comment: Yes understand. But the problem is, I'm going to handle this in Splunk. I wouldn't know whether this is possible with Splunk to handle the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that will pull all of the ip:port values from a field:

```
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "(?<ip_port>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+)"
```

Now expand the `ip_port` field:

```
| mvexpand ip_port
```

And then extract from `ip_port` into `ip` & `port`:

```
| rex field=ip_port "(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\)\:(?<port>\d+)"
```